# How to lookup a value from another column and display Row number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm setting up an excel file for the operators. They will scan the Barcode from the product and it will populate in one of the column of the excel sheet.
I have tried using LOOKUP formula in excel but it doesn't seem to be working right.

COL A : Data from Database
COL B : Data from Scanner
COL C:  Row number

Find the value of Column B in Col A and populate the Row no. in Column C.

=LOOKUP(B5,A:A,ROW(A:A))

I have used this formula in every cell of the column C.
[image]

The row number don't populate accurately.

[image: I want to display GOOD OR BAD in ROW 2. GOOD - IF the scanner reads 6 barcodes and BAD if less than 6]
[image: How to change color to RED if the value is greater than 0?]

Comment: How to change color to RED if the SUM value in Col D is greater than 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search B column in A column and get row back. You could use:

**Note:**

1. Do not forget to use IFNA in case of B does not included in A.
2. In my opinion there is no need to target whole range.

   =IFNA(MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$6,0)+ROW($A$1:$A$6)-1,"")

**Results:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`=MATCH(B5,A:A,0)` should give you the rownumber. And if you wish to obtain the cell's address: `=ADDRESS(MATCH(B5,A:A,0),1,4,1)`

If you are using combined cells then you definiately want to use absolute ranges like `=MATCH(B5,$A$5:$A$10,0)`

Comment: Thank you so much JvDv! Works like a charm.

Comment: How do I display Good, Bad or Duplicate result? Every time the scanner triggers, it should read 6 barcodes. If it reads 6 unique it's good. If anything less than 6 it should notify the amount it read in red. If it finds a duplicate it should say duplicate found in particular row.

Comment: I'm confused to what you ask, could you please update your question with this new information with sample data/input and expected outcome.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to display GOOD, BAD, or DUPLICATE in ROW 2. GOOD: When the Barcode scanner reads all  6 barcodes  BAD: If less than 5 DUPLICATE: If there are duplicate numbers in column C , it should say duplicate in ROW 2